# Spring Batch: move files to another location

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to use Spring Batch to perform the upload of files from my server to e.g. Google Drive.
So the steps are:

1. get files from a specified folder
2. upload them to Google Drive
3. update each entry in my DB corresponding to this file (i.e. update path)

My question is: do I necessarily have to do it with tasklet? If so, do I have to split the job into chunks myself and there will be no restart-on-failure support?

Comment: Why would this have to be a task let. You clearly defined 3 steps, 2 of them can be a task let, processing the file is basic chunk oriented processing. Also Step 1 and 2 might be even better suited for Spring Integration (which works quite nicely with Spring Batch).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your recommendation, I'm going to get to know with it very soon.